# Realm database report "No RealmObjects. Has linker stripped them?" on Windows10

Tags: c#, .net, realm

When using realm database on VisualStudio2015(C#), Realm report exception like below:

```
No RealmObjects. Has linker stripped them? See https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#linker-stripped-schema
   Location: Realms.Schema.RealmSchema.Builder.Build()
   Location: System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   Location: System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   Location: Realms.Realm.GetInstance(RealmConfigurationBase config, RealmSchema schema)
```

**Details:**

my code is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Realm install by using Nuget to my Project, and Realm version is 3.2.1.
Of course, this project include "FodyWeavers.xml" like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Weavers>
  <RealmWeaver />
</Weavers>
```

I think Realm can use in .Net application on Windows10, am I wrong?
If anyone know how to use Realm and if you have sample source, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

use `RealmConfigiration` and then initialize the instance.

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration(); 

var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
```

You can also intialize RealmConfiguration with a path like

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration("MyDB/myrealm.realm");
```

Important thing is Realm only supports UWP, Android , iOS(Xamarin) projects when its C#.

If you are using it for `WPF` or `WinRT` it wont work.

Comment: woops....I thought the realm works on windows form application...I will try to use UWP...

Comment: Please upvote and accept answer if I addressed your issue